# Can't I use log4j without slf4j?

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to use `log4j` for a simple, small maven application that runs as a JAR. I understand that there are benefits of `slf4j`, but I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible, without resorting to `System.out`

I have the following in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

It mainly works, it is logging to a file as my `log4j.properties` directs. But ...

... I get the following in my console:

```
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
```

It seems like this might be coming from the following dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

since logging directly works, and the error is thrown when `commons-httpclient` stuff is encountered.

I've experimented with adding various `slf4j` dependencies to my `pom.xml` but nothing has helped, and it isn't helping my to understand the actual problem.

Is there a way to just use `log4j` without any errors? If not, how can this error be eliminated?

Comment: Seems like `commons-logging` is trying to direct to `slf4j` instead of `log4j`. Check with `mvn dependency:tree` to see if there's another dependency that's bringing in `slf4j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your dependency tree with

```
 mvn dependency:tree
```

to find out which dependency has transitive slf4j dependency. I doubt that it is commons-httpclient as it only has the follwing dependencies (and uses commons logging):

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ log4j ---
[INFO] binding:log4j:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
```

You finally have to find out which slf4j-api version is used (check with `mvn dependency:resolve`) and provide a matching log4j binding lib (see [SLF4J Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>x.x.x</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Huh, seems I have two. `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7` and `org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.5`. I tried putting both in the `pom.xml` but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, you have a default binding to Java Util Logging (JDK) what is probably not what you want. You should exclude that transitive dependency (do you know how?). If no binding is provided _slf4j-api will default to a no-operation implementation discarding all log requests_.

Answer (score 1):

Try first to check which of your other project dependencies rely on `slf4j`

`mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenScrap 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ MavenScrap  ---
[INFO] sub.optimal:MavenScrap:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to understand some differences.

## For Library makers

In this case we are developing a java library, with the future aim to be included in a project. So if we want to go to heaven, **we should not use a proprietary logging provider** (logback, log4j, jdk logging) inside a library. We can think that the project which will use our library is free to use any logger provider.

For this scenario, SLF4J help us.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**sample.java**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
Logger.info("hello");
```

Now you see logging output on STDOUT with INFO level. This simple logger will default show any INFO level message or higher. In order to see DEBUG messages, you would need to set the level as a System Property at your Java startup (choose one)

- `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG`
- `System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel", "DEBUG");`

---

## For apps maker

In this case we are not developing a library. So we are free to use any logger provider of our preference. In my case I love log4j2.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

**src/main/resources/log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**sample.java**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
Logger.info("hello");
```

With these minimal configurations you will have a happy and healthy logs  using your log4j configurations.

And if your imported libraries which use SLF4J, you will see its logs in the same channel of your log4j.

But if your imported libraries which not use SLF4J, for example: logback or jdk-logging, you can not see their logs in the same channel of your **log4j** and probably will be a nightmare

---

## References

- https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-slf4j-different

Comment: You can get the exact same behavior by using the Log4j 2 API.  It will give you exactly the same implementation freedom as SLF4J with a richer API.

Comment: If my library use Log4j 2 API, and the application uses logback like spring-boot, what will happen with logger.info inside of my library?

Comment: SLF4J is the API for Logback just like Log4j-api is the API for Log4j-core. When you want to use Log4j with SLF4J logger calls go to log4j-slf4j-impl then to Log4j-api and then to log4j-core. If you use the Log4j-api with Logback then Log4j-api calls go to log4j-to-slf4j, slf4j and then to Logback.  Calls to logger.info will work regardless of which API and which implementation you choose so long as you have the correct bridging jars in place. The only difference is that the Log4j-api has more features than SLF4J and Log4j is more actively maintained. SLF4J has only had 2 commits this year.